# Swapping Keys with AutoHotKey

Tags: windows-10, autohotkey

My laptop is a Lenovo Yoga 910 with Windows 10.  I'm trying to use AutoHotKey to make the following mapping:

```
PgUp::RShift
RShift::PgUp
End::PgDn
PgDn::Right
```

However, with the exception of the `RShift::PgUp` re-map, it simply refuses to acknowledge any of these mappings.  I suspected this was because my mapping is causing keys to be "swapped" or overlapped. So I studied [this example](https://autohotkey.com/board/topic/124519-remapping-key-without-overriding-hotkeys/), and made another attempt:

```
$PgUp::Send {RShift}
$RShift::Send {PgUp}
$End::Send {PgDn}
$PgDn::Send {Right}
```

The above also did not work.  What am I missing?

I am able to make other mappings work successfully.  For example, the rest of the mappings in the same ahk script work just fine:

```
+BS::send {Delete}
$Del::End
Insert::Home
#v::
  Run, notepad.exe
Return
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4):

I think you are correct that it is overlapping the remaps, so it maps to one then proceeds and maps back to the first.  You can resolve this by putting a `return` after each `send` command.

```
$PgUp::
    Send {RShift}
    Return
$RShift::
    Send {PgUp}
    Return
$End::
    Send {PgDn}
    Return
$PgDn::
    Send {Right}
    Return
```

This ends up causing the whole script to stop remapping after it hits the `return` until the next key is pressed.